# How can I set the background during transition?

Tags: android, material-design, android-transitions

Hello I am new with transitions.
During transition, You can see a white background being hidden.
[image]

Activity-A --->Activity-B

(Setup animation in A)

```
private fun setupWindowAnimations() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            // A (general activity) --> B ((this , detail activity))
            val slide = Slide(Gravity.LEFT)
            slide.duration = 500
            window.enterTransition = slide

            // A (general activity) <-- B ((this, detail activity))
            val fade = Fade()
            fade.duration = 1000
            window.returnTransition = fade

        }
```

(Trigger of animation in viewHolder-A)

```
override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        if (view != null) {
            val intent: Intent = Intent(view.context, DisksActivity::class.java)
            val bundle: Bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString(view.context.getString(R.string.EXTRA_DISK_TITLE), itemView.tag.toString())
            intent.putExtras(bundle)
            val sharedView: View = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cd_room_title)
            val transitionName: String  = view.context.getString(R.string.transition_disk_name_title)
            val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                    view.context as Activity, sharedView, transitionName)
            view.context.startActivity(intent,options.toBundle())
        }

    }
```

(Setup animation in B)

```
private fun setupWindowAnimations() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            // A (general activity) --> B ((this , detail activity))
            val slide = Slide(Gravity.LEFT)
            slide.duration = 500
            window.enterTransition = slide

            // A (general activity) <-- B ((this, detail activity))
            val fade = Fade()
            fade.duration = 1000
            window.returnTransition = fade

        }
}
```

(The main layout of both)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/rock_background"
  tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">
```

[image]

How can I set the background during transition ?
or
Do you know some workaround?

Thank you!

Comment: The main layout of "both" : the activity B use other tools:context of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the windowBackground using theme  for the second Activity might help .

Create a drawable and name it  as background.xml to be set as the window background for the second activity with shows , until the layout is loaded :-

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
</layer-list>
```

Next step is to create a theme for the second activity in the styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>

</style>
```

Now set the theme for the second activity by setting the `android:theme="@style/Theme"`
attribute inside your activity tag in the manifest.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Keveri. That work for me. When I thought "I know how to use the manifest"...I discover that the main layout ignore the theme and use the manifest settings.